# How can I use threading with requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

Hello I am using the requests module and I would like to improve the speed because I have many urls so I suppose I can use threading to have a better speed. Here is my code :

```
import requests

urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.apple.com", "http://www.microsoft.com", "http://www.amazon.com", "http://www.facebook.com"]
for url in urls:
    reponse = requests.get(url)
    value = reponse.json()
```

But I don't know how to use requests with threading ...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Just to add from bashrc, you can also use it with requests.
You don't need to use urllib.request method.

it would be something like :

```
from concurrent import futures

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor: ## you can increase the amount of workers, it would increase the amount of thread created
    res = executor.map(requests.get,URLS)
responses = list(res) ## the future is returning a generator. You may want to turn it to list.
```

What I like to do however, it is to create a function that returns directly the json from the response (or the text if you want to **scrape**).
And use that function in the threadpool

```
import requests
from concurrent import futures
URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

def getData(url):
   res = requests.get(url)
   try:
       return res.json()
   except:
       return res.text
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    res = executor.map(getData,URLS)
responses = list(res) ## your list will already be pre-formated
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [concurrent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module.

```
    pool = concurrent.futures.thread.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_THREADS)
    pool.map(lambda x : requests.get(x), urls)
```

This allows controlled concurrency.

This is a [direct example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) from the `threadpool` documentation

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```